# how to pass variables in cakephp2.3 between a plugin and a controller without connection?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I am using cakephp 2.3 recently, and I came a doubt.
  I need to pass an array (variable), a plugin for a controller, both of which do not have direct connection.

I wonder of you, what better way to pass this variable, no link between two files?

For example I am researching using:

where I need to record this variable.

```
Configure::write('idParaImagens', $id);
```

and this where I need to read this variable.

```
Configure::read('idParaImagens');
```

the question is,
  how this variable will be widely used, this would be the best way to do this?
  for safety, certainty of reading and writing, etc., it would be best to do?

Answer (score 0):

I would write method in plugin, that returns needed array. Either in plugin's Component or plugin's helper depending on where you need this data. It will be straight and clear where this data comes from.

Using `Configure::write()` and `Configure::read()` or Session for passing variables between plugin and application will be pain in ass to maintain later.